# Deleting the file in CompilerResults.PathToAssembly

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, delete-file, system.reflection

I have generated a dynamic assembly and want to save it in the database. To do this I in the Compiler Parameters set the GenerateInmemory as false and then passed outputassembly path as C:\xxx.dll. 
Then I am doing File.ReadAllBytes(CompilerResults.PathToAssembly) and saving this byte[] to the database. After I am done with all this, I am trying to delete the file I am getting access denied error File Open error. 
Is there are way to close file and then delete the file?

```
    CompilerParameters cParams = new CompilerParameters();
                    cParams.GenerateInMemory = false;
                    cParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
                    CodeDomProvider cProvider =
    CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
                    cParams.OutputAssembly = @"c:\xxx.dll";

                    cParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                    cParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");


                    CompilerResults cr =
    cProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cParams, sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());

                    if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
                        }
                    }
    Assembly assembly =cr.CompiledAssembly;
    byte[] assemblyAsArray = File.ReadAllBytes(cr.PathToAssembly);
      ...........
//save to database here 

File.Delete(@"c:\xxx.dll")  => getting error here
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am defining assembly from the compiled assembly, it was loading in the appdomain to the file path. Once I created the byte save to database and then delete the files and load assembly from the path worked.

```
            CompilerResults cr =
    cProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cParams, sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());

                    if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
                        }
                    }
    //Assembly assembly =cr.CompiledAssembly;
    byte[] assemblyAsArray = File.ReadAllBytes(cr.PathToAssembly);
      ...........
//save to database here 

File.Delete(@"c:\xxx.dll") ;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyAsArray);
```